# Ctrl-Shift Arrow key broken?

Tags: shortcut, graph-editor, navigation

I thought ctrl-shift arrowkey L & R was supposed to hop between markers, but it doesn't seem to work any more (2.93.5)?

Answer (score 1):

You can always assign a hotkey via context menu:

[image]